# UIPopoverController and content ViewController - memory management question

Tags: ios, xcode, memory-management, uipopovercontroller

Please check my approach concerning release of both UIPopoverController and loadViewController

```
- (IBAction) manageCardSets:(UIBarButtonItem*)baritem {
    LoadViewController *loadViewController = [[LoadViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain]; 

    self.loadPopover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:loadViewController];
    self.loadPopover.delegate = self;

    [self.loadPopover presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:baritem permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown animated:YES];   

    [loadViewController release];
}

- (void)popoverControllerDidDismissPopover:(UIPopoverController *)popoverController {

    [popoverController.contentViewController release];
    self.loadPopover = nil;
    [_loadPopover release]; 
}
```

As you can see I release loadViewController twice and the code works, no leaks, but I have some doubts.
If I release it once, than the dealloc is not called in loadViewController.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `loadPopover` property is retain/copy, the following line  is **over-retaining** the object and leaking:

```
self.loadPopover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:loadViewController];
```

Both, alloc-init and the property accessor retain the object. This should be:

```
self.loadPopover = [[[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:loadViewController] autorelease];
```

This is why the `loadPopover` object only gets deallocated if you send it two release messages but **you should never resort to these tricks**.

**EDIT:**

You also have another memory management problem. You are releasing an object you do not own in this line:

```
[popoverController.contentViewController release];
```

It is the `popoverController` responsability to retain/release the `contentViewController`. By doing this you are **over-releasing** the `contentViewController`.

To sum up, your code would look like this:

```
- (IBAction) manageCardSets:(UIBarButtonItem*)baritem {
    LoadViewController *loadViewController = [[LoadViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain]; 

    self.loadPopover = [[[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:loadViewController] autorelease];
    self.loadPopover.delegate = self;

    [self.loadPopover presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:baritem permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown animated:YES];   

    [loadViewController release];
}

- (void)popoverControllerDidDismissPopover:(UIPopoverController *)popoverController {
    self.loadPopover = nil;
}
```

Comment: ...or `loadPopover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:loadViewController];` +1 for correct answer

Comment: probably is still better to assign _loadPopover which is the ivar according to the initial example; loadPopover symbol should be left to accessors only ( setLoadPopover: and loadPopover: )

Comment: @viggio24 Are you suggesting not to use the property within the class? Because I have to disagree, properties encapsulate memory management code and thus reduce boilerplate. If you assign the backing ivar `_loadPopover` directly, you have to make sure to release its previous value.

Comment: @albertamg I'm just saying that according to the initial example, there is a _loadPopover defined, so probably the user synthesized it in this way: @synthesize loadPopover = _loadPopover; So you cannot do loadPopover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] ...] as Till suggested, it generates a compilation error as _loadPopover is defined, while loadPopover is used to generate the accessor names only (or for the dot notation). Anyway I agree with you that if you synthesize a property it is better to access it using the accessor and not the ivar

Comment: @viggio24 ok now I see what you meant :)

Comment: @albertamg @viggio24 Thank you for you answers, sorry that I did not show @property (nonatomic, retain) UIPopoverController *loadPopover;
and  @synthesize  loadPopover=_loadPopover; The problem is that autorelease does not work for the case with UIPopoverController.

Comment: @Michael What do you mean by "The problem is that autorelease does not work for the case with UIPopoverController"? Maybe I did not make myself clear but in that line you are over-retaining the `loadPopover` object and it is an error that needs correcting.

Comment: @albertamg I had a crash, but I've changed the code, self.loadPopover = [[[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:loadViewController] autorelease]; and I release loadViewController in - (void)popoverControllerDidDismissPopover:(UIPopoverController *)popoverController only. Now dealloc is called in loadViewController.

Comment: @Michael Please see my edit about `loadViewController`. `[popoverController.contentViewController release];` is **wrong** because you do not own the object. You can release it in `manageCardSets:` because `loadPopover` will retain it.

Comment: @albertamg I forgot about this rule "do not own do not release". As far as I understand dealloc in loadViewController will be called as soon as loadPopover is autoreleased. And two more question is bothering me about autorelease in init of loadPopover. Can I release it in dealloc? In some sample codes I can see initiation using accessor and without autorelease with further release in dealloc. What is your opinion?

Comment: @Michael (1) dealloc in `loadViewController` will be called when `loadPopover` (its last owner) releases it. (2) You *should* release all your retain/copy properties in dealloc. (3) As long as you do not over-retain the object you can use alloc-init-autorelease or use a temporary local variable to alloc-init, then invoke the accessor, then release it or use a convenience constructor, which returns an object you do not own.

Comment: @albertamg thank you for the lesson! So self.myString = [NSString stringWithStrin:@"la-bla"] is OK. And other way NSString *tempVar = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"Bla-bla"]; self.myString = tempVar; [tempVar release]; is also OK. Of course in both cases I have to release myString in dealloc. Did I understand you?